# How to avoid redundantly downloading data when using switchMap and inner observables in RxFire?

Tags: firebase, rxjs, rxfire

I have some RxFire code that listens to a Firestore collection query (representing *channels*) and, for each of the results, listens to a Realtime Database ref for documents (representing *messages* in that channel).

The problem I'm running into is that the Realtime Database documents are re-downloaded every time the Firestore query changes, even if they're for a path/reference that hasn't changed.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```js
collection(channelsQuery).pipe(

  // Emits full array of channels whenever the query changes
  switchMap(channels => {

    return combineLatest(
      channels.map(channel =>

        // Emits the full set of messages for a given channel
        list(getMessagesRef(channel)),
      ),
    );
  })
)
```

Imagine the following scenario:

- Query intially emits **3** Firestore channel documents
- Observables are created for corresponding Realtime Database refs for those 3 channels, which emit their message documents
- A new Firestore document is added that matches the original query, which now emits **4** channel documents
- The previous observables for Realtime Database are destroyed, and new ones are created for the now **4** channels, re-downloading and emitting all the data it already had for the previous **3**.

Obviously this is not ideal as it causes a lot of redundant reads on the Realtime Database.  What's the best practice in this case?  Keep in mind that when a channel is removed, I would like to destroy the corresponding observable, which `switchMap` already does.